# Counting string using for loop

Tags: python

I don't know what I am doing wrong. When I input a string it gives me back the letter but only gives the occurrence of 1. Can somebody tell what I am doing wrong.

```
def printDictionary(a):
    c=sorted(a)
    for char in c:
        print(char, c.count(char))
```

PS I'm new to python

Comment: Can you provide us some input you would be using along with the expected output?

Comment: When I run this for "apple", I get back 
('a', 1)('e', 1)
('l', 1)
('p', 2)
('p', 2). What is it about this that you don't like?

Comment: As a side note, while it's worth learning how to do this yourself (especially if it's a class assignment), in real-life code you'd probably want to just use `c = collections.Counter(a)` and then `for char, count in sorted(c.items()): print(char, count)`.

Comment: it not clear what you passing , can you provide sample input and expected output??

Comment: I was trying to get an output with out tuples, list, and dictionary's but, thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work when passed a string:

```
>>> printDictionary('abcaab')
a 3
a 3
a 3
b 2
b 2
c 1
```

So I assume that you are passing dictionaries to `printDictionary()` (only seems logical)...

The line

```
c=sorted(a)
```

assigns to `c` the sorted *keys* of the dictionary `a`. Since dictionary keys are unique there can only ever be one instance of that key in a dictionary, hence `c.count(char)` always returns 1.

```
>>> printDictionary(dict(a=1,b=10,zz=22,ABC=1033))
ABC 1
a 1
b 1
zz 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this dictionary:

```
{'a': ['ant', 'abacus'], 'b': ['bear']}
```

And you want to get this output:

```
a 2
b 1
```

Then use this function:

```
def printDictionary(dictionary):
    keys = sorted(dictionary)
    for key in keys:
        print(key, len(dictionary[key]))
```